# Highcharts: Updating a Pie with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to update the pie's data when the li is clicked. If data.php $cid get the value fixed value it works. Example : user_student.cid = 1 will work. If i use  user_student.cid = $cid it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea?

---

Thanks you,pquest.

But there have some problems.If I use fixed value 1 ,the alert value is: [["apple",1],["banana",2],["orange",3]] and the pie is working. If I use $cid value(if $cid value is 1) , the value alert is:[["apple",1],["banana",2],["orange",3]] but the pie is not working.

Anyone have any idea?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {



            $('table.display').dataTable({
                "paging":   false,
                "info":     false
            });

    $('li').click(function(){


    var cid = $(this).attr("id");
     $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'data.php',
                    data:{ cid:cid },
                    success:function(reponse){

                    alert(reponse)
                    /*options.series[0].data = reponse;
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);*/
                    }

                });


        var options = {
        chart: {
                    renderTo: 'pie',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
        title: {
                    text: 'Web Sales & Marketing Efforts'
                },
 tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
    percentageDecimals: 1,
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1); +' %';
    }
},
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: '#000000',
                            connectorColor: '#000000',
                            formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1); +' %';
    }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    name: 'Browser share',

                    data: []
                }]
            }




            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });




    });



        });
  </script>
```

---

data.php

```
    <?php

require_once("../connectDB.php");


$cid = isset($_POST["cid"]) ? $_POST["cid"] : "";

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT stu_info.reference FROM stu_info , user_student WHERE stu_info.sid = user_student.sid and user_student.cid = :cid");
$result ->execute(array(':cid'  => $cid,));



 $one = 0; $two = 0; $three = 0; 

while($r = $result -> fetch()) {

    if($r['reference'] === "apple")
        $one = $one+1;
    else

    if($r['reference'] === "banana")
        $two = $two+1;
    else

    if($r['reference'] === "orange")
        $three = $three+1;

}


$ra = array($one,$three,$two);
$rb = array(apple,banana,orange);



$rows = array();
 for($i=0 ; $i<=2 ; $i=$i+1)
 {
    $row[0] = $rb[$i];
    $row[1] = $ra[$i];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}


print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);



?>
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if `cid` is getting a value?

Comment: Yes,I use ajax alert too see the value. When I only echo $cid the value is right value and print json is Correct,too.The json's array is update(ajax success and the alert's value is right) but the pie isn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just write `$cid` in the query text. You have to build the string:

```
"SELECT stu_info.reference FROM stu_info , user_student WHERE stu_info.sid = user_student.sid and user_student.cid = "  . $cid
```

Edit: It looks like the concatenation operator in php is `.` Rather than `+`

Comment: But I change to user_student.cid = :cid
$result ->execute(array(':cid' => $cid,));

alert the value is right but the pie still not working.

Comment: If I use fixed value 1 ,the alert value is:  [["apple",1],["banana",2],["orange",3]] and the pie is working.
If i use $cid value(if $cid value is 1) , the value alert is:[["apple",1],["banana",2],["orange",3]] but the pie is not working

Comment: Have you stepped through your code starting at ` $one = 0; $two = 0; $three = 0;` to make sure every variable is actually getting the value you expect?

Comment: Yes,sorry my English is poorly.My question is all the value is the same. But if i use fixed value pie is working(have a picture).But if I use cid and get the value from sql.Pie is not working(all the value show on pie is Zero),But ajax alert(json array) are all the same.